# Как сделать жест обновления android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, listview

Каким образом можно добавить свайп вниз у ExpandableListView, такой же как, к примеру, в ютюб и ВК для обновления ленты или в gmail для обновления списка писем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните нужную вьюху в `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Вот дока по ней: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/swiperefreshlayout